# Which list i should use for storing players infos?

Tags: c#, list, tuples

Am making a Game Server in C#,am using UDP as protocol and i have to store users infos in a list so i can later loop through to get,set a value for the chosen player.
I tried a list of tuple like this but i found that tuples are read-only and i need to get,set the player position multiple times per second.
I tried:

```
List<tuple<int, IPENDPOINT, string, string,>> usersInfos = new List<tuple<int,IPENDPOINT, string, string>>();
```

but since they are read-only i can only add tuple to the list,what should i use to be able to set,get player infos like 'id & Endpoint & username & current position' ?
I need to get,set current position multiple times per second.
Any way to achieve that ? even without tuples.
Thanks

Comment: Am planing to be able to get those infos multiple times per second per player will that be problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `UserInfo` class with the properties `Id`, `EndPoint`,`UserName` and `CurrentPosition`. Then just have a list of `UserInfos`.

Comment: Any example ? and can i extend it to store more than ID,EndPoint..... without affecting the previous list ?